# Which theoretical models for quantum computing are polynomial-time equivalent?

Tags: computational-models

There are different theoretical models for quantum computing like the circuit model or the model of adiabatic quantum computers.

Between which of these models exist polynomial-time reductions?

Note that this question does not aim to cover physical implementations of quantum computers which are already discussed [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/how-should-different-quantum-computing-devices-be-compared).

Comment: There is a nice work on it from 2016, I haven't read all but it is a nice start: [arXiv:1611.04471](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.04471).

Comment: Related: [What are the methods of quantum computation?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/74/what-are-the-methods-of-quantum-computation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-exhaustive list of theoretical models of quantum computation are provided as answers to another question: "[What are the methods of quantum computation?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/74/what-are-the-methods-of-quantum-computation)".

As to which models are polynomial-time equivalent — the following is an incomplete list of models which are provably universal for polynomial-time quantum computation, assuming perfect control:

- The unitary circuit model is polynomial-time equivalent to adiabatic quantum computation [[arXiv:quant-ph/0405098](http://arXiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0405098)];
- The unitary circuit model is polynomial-time equivalent to quantum circuits with intermediate measurements (by the principle of deferred measurement);
- The one-way measurement-based model is polynomial-time equivalent to unitary circuits.