# How can I use the quantum volume to design the scale of my experiment?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, hhl-algorithm, quantum-volume

I am designing an experiment which involves solving a linear system of equations of the form $Ax=b$. To do this, I am using the HHL algorithm on the IBMQ system. My experiment is scalable such that the size of matrix $A$ can be as large or small as I choose it to be. I would like to tailor the size of my matrix $A$ to be as large as possible but still within the computation limit of the quantum computer that I use. My suspicion is that to determine this I need to account for the quantum volume of the IBMQ machine that I use, but I do not understand exactly how.

Here is a little more information that may be useful. My experiment is adapted from the code in this [HHL tutorial](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/hhl_tutorial.html) describing the general method to run the algorithm (section 4A). This means that I have **not** optimized the algorithm in any way. That being said, an example of the resource requirements for a modestly sized matrix $A$ for my experiment are as follows:

```
circuit_width:   11
circuit_depth:   101
CNOT gates:      54
```

My question is, how can I use these numbers to determine the quantum volume required to run my experiment?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The quantum volume is supposed to be an average measure of the quality of the quantum computer - it doesn't tell you anything on how good it will perform on solving a certain problem. (It is even questionable whether it is telling you anything meaningful, see also [Is the "Quantum Volume" a fair metric for future, elaborate, high value quantum computations?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/3985/is-the-quantum-volume-a-fair-metric-for-future-elaborate-high-value-quantum?rq=1)) A quantum volume of 64 tells you that circuits of random 2-qubit gates of width and depth 6 can be done more or less reliably on that device. Compare that to your depth of 101. Running any kind of half-way realistic algorithm on a quantum computer these days is basically an expensive way of rolling dice.